# Go debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly in VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

There is a github issue about this subject. I couldnot find any clue from this github issue. (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1052) 
I have reinstalled vscode go extension and delve. I have controlled all environmental settings. But I haven't solved the problem.

Any suggestions what might be wrong with debugging?

```
VS Code version: 1.22.2
Go version: 1.9.1
Go VS Code Extension: 0.6.78 
Window 10 Pro x64

"configurations": [ {
    "name": "Delve",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "debug",
    "remotePath": "",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "program": "E:/Qlass/goserv/src/",
    "args": [],
    "showLog": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem originated from the project directory change. 
After changing the folder of the project, you reinstall all the go tools in VS Code to run debugger.

```
Installing 16 tools at E:\Qlass\goserv\bin
gocode
gopkgs
go-outline
go-symbols
guru
gorename
gomodifytags
goplay
impl
fillstruct
godef
godoc
goreturns
golint
gotests
dlv
```